# Django(Python) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, django, server

I get strange error when I visit post page. I make web application where you can post images and videos. With images it work fine, but when I post video and go to its page, server give me following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 593, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[15/May/2016 13:50:09] "GET /media/uploads/Big_Buck_Bunny_Final.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 500 59

----------------------------------------

Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 23943)
[15/May/2016 13:50:09] "GET /static/image/video-poster.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 593, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 92, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 628, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 99, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 684, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Slavko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Code for images and videos is same and that is reason why I don't understand this.
Here is my view function, that is used when you visit post page:

```
def post_info(request, pk):
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    same_author_posts = Post.objects.filter(author=post.author)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.post = post
            instance.save()
            form = CommentForm()
            messages.success(request, 'Comment is approved!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/post/%s/'%(pk))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Comment is not valid!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/post/%s/'%(pk))
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'post': post,
        'same_author_posts': same_author_posts,
    }
    return render(request, 'post/post_info.html', context)
```

Probably it have something with status code in respons, but why it don't show it when images is loaded and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the directory you are storing the file into?

Comment: Yes, everything is normal. I notice that sometime same error is raised when for example 127.0.0.1:8000 change to 127.0.0.1:9000. But still I can understand why he don't show that when I go to post_info.html to see picture, only video output error.

Comment: what did you find? ):
I have the same error

Comment: I was working on some school project. I find that that error occur when file is too big. I don't know reason for that. For example, I make website where you can post images or video and many more things. Problem was when browser render video or large image, so I compress video and it was working fine. But when I run same video on laptop(that is slower than my PC) it show same error. So, I think that it is some bug with Django developing server (in my case). That error don't stop website or anything else, it was still working fine. Try to compress your files and you will not see error again.

Comment: Also, I find that server open new connection, but don't close old. As I say on my PC it was working fine, on laptop I was need to compress it one more time. It have some connection with size of files and speed of computer... It can also happen that some of your functions ,,return None" (I read that somewhere).

Comment: For anyone wondering what this might be, this is a [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue27682) related to the wsgiref Handler in Python...

Comment: This is fixed in version 3.7.4. See more [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9713)

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with firewall/antivirus disabled